# Javascript sending the wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I am trying to send values to an mysql database using ajax from a form. I am selecting the value by taking the parent article of the form and then taking the child element with id="email" as you can see here...

```
var email = $(this).parent("article").children("#email").val() //gets the user's email
```

However when I send the data onto the php file for uploading to the mysql database it seems to be doing something wrong, and instead of the value typed in being stored a function (shown below) is being stored... What is going on here!?

```
function (a) {var c,d,e,g=this[0];{if(!!arguments....
```

Comment: So have you checked the `email` variable value? Have you tried to see what's actually sent with firebug?

Comment: is the value proper before you send it off?

Comment: Your email field has an id, so just use `$('#email').val()`, or, because you really don't need to use jQuery for every single thing, `document.getElementById('email').value`.

Comment: Technically, you cannot supose id is unique. Of course, you should make ids unique, but maybe he has an awful case where it is necessary. Just saying... http://jsfiddle.net/NmMGW/

Comment: Sorry to confuse you all... email is only an id at the moment, however it will be a class and there will be multiple forms on the page which explains the need for the .parent() .child() setup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `find()` method:

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

```
var email = $(this).parent("article").find("#email").val()
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I will mark you as correct as soon as I'm allowed :)

Comment: Actually all that selector line can be replaced with `$('#email')`

Comment: Just out of interest is there any way of traversing up like this to the article? Or will parent do the job?

Comment: @simonthumper as you are selecting an element by id name. `$('#mail')` is fine, but as an alternative to `parent()`, you can use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

Comment: @zerkms actually no it can't because at some point it will become find(".email") As i want to have this form on each article on my site...

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit confusing. You're using #email, which implies an id, of which you can only have one on the page. jQuery will recognize the hashtag and default to using the native "getElementById" browser method.

So this:

```
var email = $(this).parent("article").children("#email").val()
```

Can be converted to this:

```
var email = $("#email").val()
```